# Django - replacing string in Model.objects.extra for variable

Tags: django

For example, if I have list of ids values like this:

```
values = list(set(Handler.objects.filter(blog=1).values_list('entry_id', flat=True)))
```

and i want to give variable "values" instead of numbers in string format to extra method like this:

```
Entry.objects.extra(where=['id IN (3, 4, 5, 20)'])
```

It is possible somehow to replace numbers for "values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Huh?

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__in=values)
```